# World Wide Telescope in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I am developing an APP on windows phone 7. I want to access the Microsoft World Wide Telescope data i.e i want to show the SKY VIEW on my APP with AUGMENTED REALITY just like the sky view on BING MAPS(STREET VIEW)?

Comment: and what is your question? (Saying what you want to do is not the same thing)

Comment: @ry8806 My Direct question is that,how can we access the SKY VIEW from World Wide Telescope in Windows phone?

Comment: @MattLacey  I  want to show SKY VIEW in my windows phone app from World Wide Telescope?

Comment: http://www.ted.com/talks/blaise_aguera.html Just see this video at 7:06 , u can better understand  the use of WWT :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with http://www.worldwidetelescope.org/authoring/developer.aspx

Comment: Thanks  for the link!! There is no direct SDK for Windows Phone I think. :) Can i get tutorials or samples online? I searched....whole microsoft(msdn) site, but no help :(